# How to return HTML in another page with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

So I created a form. In this form, I make GET requests to the server to search for particular users. The view responsible for using the query words returns a template as follows.

`html with the form`

```
<a href="{% url 'logout'}">Logout</a>

<p>Welcome</p>
<form id="search" method="GET" action="{% url 'results' %}" placeholder= "Choose a friend" 
autocomplete="off">
{{form}}
<input type="submit" value="search" name="search">
</form>

<a href="{% url 'liked' %}"> View Liked Songs</a>
{% endblock %}

`views to handle data passed into the form`

def results(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    search_query = request.GET.get("username")
    searched_user = UserProfile.objects.filter(
            user__username__contains=search_query
        )
    return render(
    request, "searched_results.html", {
        "searched_user":searched_user
    })
else:
    return HttpResponse("Search returned nothing")
```

This is where the issue is. Now I have two HTML files. One ought to display data returned in the results view but I want it displayed only wheni click a button in the other HTML file. This is what I mean;

I have this HTML file which is rendered when the `results/` route is used.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block  spotify %}

{%if searched_user %}
{% for each_searched_user in searched_user %}
<br/>{% for liked_songs in each_searched_user.liked_songs.all %}{{liked_songs}}<br/>
                        {% endfor %}

 {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

But I want the results endpoint to return an HTML with a button. And then, that button triggers the HTML file above to be displayed. I decided to use AJAX and create a separate `html` endpoint for the HTML above and have the `results` endpoint return `toggle.html` then I use JS to get the `html` endpoint and fill the empty div but all to no avail. How do I achieve this?

```
def html(request): 
return render(request, 
    template_name= "search_results.html"
)
```

// toggle.html

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
 {% block  spotify %}

<div id="container">
</div>

 <button id=likedsongsbutton>View liked songs</button>
 <script>
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const container= document.getElementById("container")
request.onload = function() {
if (this.status == 200) {
    document.querySelector("#likedsongsbutton").addEventListener("click", 
    () => container.innerHTML = request.responseText
    );}
else{
    console.warn("error");
}};
request.open('GET', '{% url "html" %}', true);
request.send();
</script>
{% endblock %}
```